# Basis for the null space of the vectorized identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf{I}_N$ be the $N \times N$ identity matrix. Let us define the $1 \times N^2$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ as:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A} = \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{I}_N)^T
\end{equation}
where $\mathrm{vec}$ is the column-wise vectorization operator.

Which is an orthonormal basis for the null space of $\mathbf{A}$?

Comment: A basis (orthonormal or not) for a matrix...? What is that?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I forgot to write "for the null space of"

Comment: Ok...and now explain what is that "column-wise vectorization operator". I'm guessing is some kind of rolling out the $\;n\times n\;$ matrix into an (1\times n^2\;$ vector , but how **exactly**?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, it stacks the columns of the identity matrix one after the other to get a column vector of dimension $N^2 \times 1$. Consequently, its transposed version (the matrix $\mathbf{A}$) is a $1 \times N^2$ row vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understood what you meant, we're talking about the matrix

$$A=\left(\,1,\overbrace{0,...,0}^{n-1\,\text{places}},0,1,\overbrace{0,...,0,0}^{n-2\;\text{places}},0,0,1,0,...,1\,\right)$$

and you thus want an orthonormal basis for the solution space of the homogeneous linear system of equation determined by that matrix, i.e. for the solution space of

$$x_1+x_{n+2}+x_{2n+3}+\ldots+x_{n^2}=0$$

This homogeneous system of one equation in $\;n^2\;$ unknowns have $\;n^2-n\;$ variables equal to zero:

$$x_2=x_3=\ldots=x_{n+1}=x_{n+3}=\ldots=x_{n^2-1}=0$$

and the general solution is given by the hyperplane of dimension $\;n-1\;$

$$M:=\left\{(x_1,...,x_{n^2})^t\in\Bbb F^{n^2}\;|\;x_1+x_{n+2}+\ldots+x_{n^2}=0\,,\,\,x_k=0\,,\,\,k\neq1, n+2, 2n+3,...,n^2\right\}\;$$

A basis for that, as we know from general hyperplanes(=kernels of linear functionals) is

$$\left\{\,(v_1, v_2,..., v_{n-1})\,\right\}\,,\,\,\text{with}\;v_1=\left(\,1,\overbrace{0,...,0}^{n-0\,\text{places}},0,0,\overbrace{0,...,0,0}^{n-2\;\text{places}},0,0,0,0,...,-1\,\right)$$

$$v_2=\left(\,0,\overbrace{0,...,0}^{n-1\,\text{places}},0,1,\overbrace{0,...,0}^{n-2\;\text{places}},0,...,-1\,\right)\,,\ldots,v_{n_1}=\left(\,0,\overbrace{0,...,0}^{n-1\,\text{places}},0,\overbrace{0,...,0}^{n-2\;\text{places}},0,1,0,...,-1\,\right)$$

If you "erase" (in your imagination) all the zeros, these are simply the $\;n-1\;$ vectors

$$(1,0,...,0,-1), (0,1,0,...,0,-1)\,...,(0,...,0,1,-1)$$

Well, now just apply Gram-Schmidt to this base and we shall be done.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I was wondering if it would be possible to express this basis in a compact "matrix form"... I'll work on it!